# Google Apps via Apple Mail Not Sending

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

The problem only began within the last couple of weeks (or so I can tell).

I use Google Apps for all of my organizations, of which there are several, and I have them all set up in Apple Mail (as well as on my phone, etc.).

All of a sudden, some percentage of the time, when I send an email through Apple Mail (on OS X), everything appears to work but it does not. The little progress bar at the bottom of the main window pops up and completes, the email appears to have sent and I go on my way.

I've now had a few people tell me they didn't get emails from me that they were expecting (even in spam), and here is the weird part: when I look in my sent folder, they are not there. I've also logged into the Gmail Web App, and they also are not in the sent folder there!

I seem to be receiving just fine, and a majority of the time, the mail I send is delivered.

At first I thought I was crazy, and just remembered wrong—that I hadn't really sent what I thought. But it's happened multiple times now, and I can't figure it out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like it might be an Apple Mail problem. Have you asked on [apple.se]?

Comment: @AlE. I haven't. You may be right. I've done some more testing and it seems that messages sent directly from Gmail.com are going through. Will update if I find out more.